# How to troubleshoot "Close All Windows" menu option not working?

Tags: windows, putty, user-interface

I have an application with several windows open. When right-clicking and selecting `Close all windows` from the context menu nothing happens and the windows remain open. How can I troubleshoot this? Is there an error log? I've tried looking at the Windows Event Viewer in the System log but haven't found anything related.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 in case that matters and the application in question is Putty.

Comment: Did you check whenever putty is waiting for configuration in order to close the window?

Comment: @Seth Not sure what you mean, but these were putty windows of (stale) ssh connections and not the putty configuration window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will not write to any logs (in the Event Viewer or elsewhere) in the case clicking **Close All** doesn't work.  It's possible, though doubtful, the offending application itself may generate a logged event.  If so, one would expect that to be written to the Windows Application event log, or an application-specific log file.

Assuming your problem is limited to a specific application, it's reasonable to assume the root cause lies with how the application is handling Windows' instruction to close all of its child windows and then terminate.  A few explanations come to mind:

1. The application **cannot** close. This could be due to an open dialog box that requires input or some other program-specific constraint.  The proper way to handle this is notify the user of the requirement. For example, many applications will play the Windows Error Sound (*ding!*), or flash the application's window button in the Taskbar.
2. The application **fails** to close. The reasons for this can vary widely. However, if this is the case one would expect attempts to close the application via other means such as by clicking **Exit** on the File menu to fail as well.
3. The application **ignores** the Close All instruction. While I'm not a programmer and cannot speak to exactly what happens when Close All is clicked, I would guess Windows sends a message to the application informing it that the user clicked Close All. In turn, the application needs to do something about that. If the application has a bug, or simply hasn't been coded to properly handle this notification, nothing happens.

Bottom line is that dealing with the refusal to close all windows is likely to require involvement from the application's vendor.

Comment: Typically the reason is that every window has a "PuTTY Fatal Error: Network error: Software caused a connection abort" or a similar popup window. Then you have to find and click all of them before you can close the windows. How to be able to do that more quickly?